# Python: invalid syntax error while using es2csv

Tags: python-2.7

This is the query I am trying to use in order to connect to elasticsearch, which is in (172.21.150.230) in order to pull out information in a csv format:

es2csv  -u  http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:5601/ -f  _all    -d  doc -i  test2   -r  -q  '{"query": {"match": {"NAME": "xxx"}}}' -o  database.csv

However, I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using?
This error raised when your json query is not valid or when you forget to add -r argument.